# Increase and decreasing width and height of a div with set interval

Tags: javascript, html, css, setinterval, event-listener

I am doing this project for practice and I am achieving half the results but can't figure out how to the other half. Basically I have div1 with 0 width and 0 height inside a parent div2 with 280px width and height each with border radius of 50%. There is a sibling div3 of div1 with value inside. On clicking the div2 the div3 text converted into seconds and then set interval will run a function that increases the width and height proportionate to the seconds such that when seconds reach 0 height and width of div1 should be equal to parent div2. I am achieving this far and now I want to reassign seconds = 70 and decrease the width and height of div1 proportionally. My explanation might not be enough so please refer to the code snippet attached. Thanks for your help in advance.

```js
var display, time, loader, width, height, reverse, seconds, running, interval;

display = document.getElementById("display");
time = document.getElementById("time");
loader = document.getElementById("loader");
width = 0;
height = 0;
reverse = false;
running = false;
seconds = parseInt(time.textContent)*60;


if ( width === 280 && height === 280 ) {
   reverse = true;
   time.textContent = 70;
}

display.addEventListener("click" , function(){
  
  if ( running === false ) {
    running = true;
    interval = setInterval(function(){
     
      if ( reverse === false ) {
        width  += (280-width)/seconds;
        height += (280-height)/seconds;
      }
      else {
        width  -= (width/seconds);
        height -= (height/seconds);
      }
      
      loader.style.width = Math.round(width) + "px";
      loader.style.height = Math.round(height) + "px";
      console.log(width + " " + height);
      time.textContent = seconds;
      

      
      if ( seconds > 0 ) {
        seconds--;
      }
    },1000);
  }
  
  else {
    running = false;
    clearInterval(interval);
    console.log("Inteval cleared");
  }
  
});
```

```css
#display {
  width : 280px;
  height: 280px;
  border: 1px solid #5fcf80;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#time {
  font-size: 120px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 280px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9;
}

#loader {
  z-index: 1;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #5fcf80;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  
  <div id="display">
    
    <div id="time">1</div>
    <div id="loader"></div>
    
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some mistakes in your code:

**1- The following `if` clause is useless because its contents never executes:**

```
if ( width >= 280 && height >= 280 ) {
   reverse = true;
   time.textContent = 70;
}
```

It never executes because this `if` is outside `addEventListener` and `setInterval`. It will run one time at the beginning, when `width` and `height` are still `0`.

**2- The following code should be at the beginning of `setInterval`:**

```
  if ( seconds > 0 ) {
    seconds--;
```

The reason is, imagine what happens when `seconds` reaches `0`:

- These lines will be executed: `width += (280-width)/seconds` and `height += (280-height)/seconds`.
- `seconds` is `0`, so a division by zero will happen!
- `width` and `height` will be `NaN` (Not a Number).

**3- The code in (2) should be:**

```
if ( seconds > 1 ) {
  seconds--;
} else if ( seconds == 1 ){
  reverse = reverse ? false : true;
  seconds = 70;
}
```

- first, we check if `seconds` is above `1` not `0`, to stop `seconds` from being `0`, and in that case, we decrease by 1.
- If `seconds` is `1`, then we've reached the max (or min) `width` and `height`.

  - In this case, if we are increasing, we will `reverse`, and vice versa.
  - In addition, we will reset `seconds` to `70` based on your specification.

**4- Based on the above changes, the initial value of `seconds` should be `61`, not `60`:**

```
seconds = parseInt(time.textContent)*61;
```

That's because we will decrease `seconds` right away in the beginning of `addEventListener`.

***Here is a working modified version on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SamiAlmalki/g5ngxuka/)***

Comment: Thank you very much, really appreciate your help. Thanks again